# How to track conversions for facebook ads if customer hasn't been redirected to tracking page

Tags: facebook, paypal

When I’m running a Conversion campaign I have my Conversion Event set to “purchases”

Everything is all set up correctly in the Events manager to keep up to date with the new IOS 14 changes.

But here’s the problem…

I’m having an issue when it comes to tracking my purchases that are made from PayPal.

You see, Facebook isn’t able to pick up PayPal payments because of the delay time during the Paypal payment confirmation window…

Customers are clicking off before being redirected back to my Order Complete page, which has the tracking info required for Facebook to track.

So in a nutshell, I’m only getting data for purchases coming back from stripe payments and losing out on the metrics of PayPal orders.

How can I get around this issue?